# How do you use the replace method to replace a single character in multiple lines of string?

Tags: python, replace

I am trying to practice some python by making a little game where multiple players can edit the contents of box. I am struggling to actually change the different elements in the box. The players can chose the 'Left' , 'Right' or 'Mid' positions of the box centre.

```
#Making the box

BoxLines = ['*****','*XYZ*','*****']
 
BoxDict= {'Line 1':BoxLines[0],'Line 2':BoxLines[1],
            'Line 3':BoxLines[2]}

 BoxCentreValues = {'Left':BoxLines[1][0],
               'Mid':BoxLines[1][1],
                'Right':BoxLines[1][2],}

 
 for line in BoxDict:
   print(BoxDict[line])
```

This outputs:

```
 *****
 *XYZ*
 *****
```

My issue is when trying to update the box values.

I have tried to use the assignment operator '==', only to be reminded that string are not mutable.
So next I tried using the replace method, but I can't get it to work as I would like it to.

```
#Testing updating the box
 
inputs = ['Left','Right','Mid']
 
for position in inputs:
   if BoxCentreValues[position] != '&':
   BoxLines[1][0].replace(" ", "&")
 
 BoxLines
```

I know that the issue is that replace makes a copy of the Boxlines string, so I should make a new variable to store this new string, but I can't figure how to.
If I try to assign the replaced string to a new variable I can only return the replaced character:

```
 #Testing updating the box
 
 inputs = ['Left','Right','Mid']
 
 for positon in inputs:
 if BoxCentreValues[position] != '&':
   updatedbox = BoxLines[1][1].replace("X", "&")
        
updatedbox
```

Outputs:

`'&'`

When I want :

```
 *****
 *&YZ*
 *****
```

Comment: The STRINGS are immutable,but you can assign a new string to `BoxLines[1]` at any time.  That's not changing a string, that's changing a list.

Comment: By the way, '==' is NOT the assignment operator, but the equality one; '=' is the assignment operator. As to your problem you might want to replace the STRING '\*XYZ\*' by a LIST, `my_list = list('*XYZ*')` ; then you can easily replace any character, and print the text with `print(''.join(my_list))` .

Answer (score 0):

I would simply reassign `BoxLines[1]` to itself with the `replace()` method.

This is what I came up with:

```
inputs = ['Left','Right','Mid']

for position in inputs:
    if BoxCentreValues[position] != '&':
        BoxLines[1] = BoxLines[1].replace('X', '&')
```

Which upon executing

```
for line in BoxLines:
    print(line)
```

Outputs:

```
*****
*&YZ*
*****
```

You'll still have the `BoxDict` assigned to the old values, so you'll either need to overwrite the old variable with the new `BoxLine` values or have the dict generated dynamically with a function at the start.

Hopefully this helps.